# Unable to Play a video from server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a URL in which i have a video which i want to play in the iphone.
This is the coding i am using.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myappdemo.com/mybusinessapp/services/video/The Simpsons - Think Differently [www.keepvid.com].mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
[[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];  // frame must match parent view
[self.view addSubview: [player view]];
[player play];
```

i am using IOS 4.3

Please give some idea
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the video in your project if it plays its not codec problem.
Try replace spaceis in the url, if video plays after that was the problem.
And my last tip remove this [www.keepvid.com] from the url if the first two is not works.
By the way the video players just working on ios devices, not on simulator.

Comment: Hi Lester, what you said is right. i just renamed the video url and its worked fine for me, thanks for the idea